# Does the Atom Editor keymap support function keys? Like F5

Tags: github, atom-editor

I setup `keymap.cson` with this entry. In the palette, I can see `F5` is associated with this command but pressing `F5` does not trigger it

`'.workspace .editor':
  'F5': 'runner:run'`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, Atom supports function keys. The names of the keys are case-sensitive and the name of <kbd>F5</kbd> is `f5`, note the lowercase "f". The following should work:

```
'atom-workspace atom-text-editor':
  'f5': 'runner:run'
```

Also, note that you may want to replace `atom-workspace atom-text-editor` with just `atom-workspace`, unless you don't want the key to execute the command when you're on the Tree View, a Markdown Preview or any other view that isn't an editor.

Comment: Doesnt seem to work for f3 for me. Looks like a conflict with find-and-replace